# On topic or off topic: questions about fonts and their usage

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are questions about fonts and their usage on-topic or off-topic? Looking at the past questions, the closing policy doesn't seem so clear-cut.

Allowed questions:

- [Is it ok to mix fonts in Japanese documents?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/is-it-ok-to-mix-fonts-in-japanese-documents)
- [What font can I use for a Japanese book?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/what-font-can-i-use-for-a-japanese-book)

Closed questions:

- [What's the difference between Hiragino Pro and ProN fonts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/whats-the-difference-between-hiragino-pro-and-pron-fonts)

Is it that general questions on font usage are on-topic, and specific questions about the characteristics of a font are off-topic?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like (from a cursory glance) that questions just about the fonts themselves are off-topic, but questions that tie in a cultural or linguistic aspect may be on-topic.  This seems similar to how questions about [Calligraphy](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=calligraphy) or [written conventions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-conventions) are treated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that all typographical questions should be closed or migrated altogether. Learning a foreign language more or less includes learning how to align letters and symbols beautifully, how to choose appropriate fonts, etc., in that language.

And I doubt one can typeset a beautiful Japanese book without the deep understanding of the Japanese language. I've seen how many professional, non-Japanese designers can easily produce ugly design works containing Japanese, even to the eyes of average Japanese people.

I agree that *technical* questions about fonts should be migrated, but if the question is purely about the aesthetic aspect regarding Japanese fonts/typography, I think there is a room for allowing it here in JLSE. I'm one of the people who frequently post answers to typographical questions, and I'm doing so in the hope that it has something to do with helping average Japanese learners, not designers.

Note I'm not saying every typographical questions should be allowed, either — we need a consensus on each subtopic, particularly on how to treat font identification questions. While [Graphic Design SE allows font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083), I can say for sure that they will be greatly bothered if all the font identification questions from languages all over the world are accumulated there.

Answer (score 2):

Font related questions are always welcome in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Most of us don't speak Japanese, but we might be able to help, at least regarding typography theory :)

Comment: I've migrated the two in the question there.

Answer (score -1):

Offtopic. All three of them.

It would be overdoing it to say "All font-related questions are offtopic", since several of [these](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=font+is%3Aquestion) are quite good questions for JLU. But questions that revolve around issues of aesthetics or layout belong on [graphic design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

Even though one of them started out with "graphic design sent me here", the original question at GD has significantly better answers than the one here.